# Visual Studio 2013 Update 5 Web config intellisense not working

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, web-config, intellisense

[image: Picture showing the error in web config]

Kindly check for the blue oval, you will see a tilde. On hovering over the tilde, I get the balloon which is marked by yellow rectangle.

Please guide me to help resolve the intellisense problem.

Comment: I believe this stackoverflow comment may help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/29925865/1000939

Answer (score 0):

Resetting Visual Studio settings or importing previously exported, working settings, and restarting Visual Studio worked:

```
Tools > Import and Export Settings... > Reset all settings.
```